# Does toPrecision behave like round then toString?

Tags: javascript

The return value of [`toPrecision`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Number/toPrecision) is "A string ... in fixed-point or exponential notation **rounded** to precision significant digits."

8.235 => "8.23" is not rounding.  Why different?

```js
var toP = function (n) {
    console.log(n, n.toPrecision(3) );
}
    
toP(1.235);  // 1.235 "1.24"
toP(2.235);
toP(3.235);
toP(4.235);
toP(5.235);
toP(6.235);
toP(7.235);
toP(8.235);  // 8.235 "8.23"  why?
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

Comment: I had to check the ES standard; [`Number.prototype.toPrecision`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number.prototype.toprecision)  It's never intended to round down. The MDN doc is slightly incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

As always, it's floating point (in)accuracy that is to blame.

1.235 in binary is 1.0011110000101000111101011100001010001111010111000011...
Truncated and converted back to decimal, you get 1.235000000000000098 which does indeed round up.

But 8.235 is 1000.0011110000101000111101011100001010001111010111...
Truncated and converted back to decimal, you get 8.234999999999999432, which rounds down.

Comment: Should always do this instead?  `Math.round(n*1000)/1000`

Comment: That would probably just shift your floating point errors around.

Comment: @KaFaiLo Check out the http://floating-point-gui.de/ for more explanations (if needed) and suggestions on how to avoid the issue.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle Good, but that site [suggests](http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/javascript/) using `toPrecision` in javascript.